# Recursively print a matrix

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion, matrix

So, I was trying to solve this exercise from my algorithm course book. The exercise asks to print recusively a matrix by subdiving the matrix into smaller squares (the matrix is always a power of 2) and to print what's inside it.
The squares must be printed from top left and then clockwise.

**So an example would be:**

> 0 0 0 0
>     0 0 0 0
>     0 1 1 1
>     0 0 0 0

And the program should print:

1. 0 0 0 0
   0 0 0 0
   0 1 1 1
   0 0 0 0
2. 0 0
   0 0
3. 0 0
   0 0
4. 0 1
   0 0
5. 1 1
   0 0

and so on.

What I tried so far is something like this(used C to check if it's right):

```
void subdivide(int x1,int x2,int y1,int y2,int n){
    if(n==0){return;}
    else{
        n = n/2;
        subdivide(x1,x2/2,y1,y2/2,n);
        subdivide(x1,x2/2,y2/2,y2,n);
        subdivide(x2/2,x2,y2/2,y2,n);
        subdivide(x2/2,x2,y1,y2/2,n);
    }
    return;
}
```

But it's not fully working for a 8x8 matrix, since it doesn't reach the corners like from (4,4) to (6,6), or (6,6) and (8,8).

Comment: Did you try debugging?

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust the positions before scaling.  I'm not sure what conventions you're using for your bounds (inclusive or exclusive), but if you want to display x range [4, 8), i.e. x index 4 (inclusive) through x index 8 (exclusive), then this needs to be broken down into [4, 6) and [6, 8) (the first number is inclusive, the second exclusive).

But you're using [x1, x2/2) which is [4, 4), and [x2/2, x2) which is [4, 8) which is your original range.

Assuming an exclusive upper bound, you need to use:

```
[x1, (x1+x2)/2)
[(x1+x2)/2, x2)
```

This produces [4, 6) and [6, 8] as desired.

Comment: yeah, I figured out that too. But still it doesn't really do the full clockwise circle as supposed. The problem is doing that in a recursive way.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void dump(int depth, int y1, int x1, int y2, int x2) {
   char indent[depth+1];

   for (int i=0; i<depth; ++i)
      indent[i] = ' ';

   indent[depth] = 0;

   printf("%s(%d,%d)(%d,%d)\n", indent, y1, x1, y2, x2);
}

// Assumes y1<=y2 && x1<=x2
void subdivide(int depth, int y1, int x1, int y2, int x2) {
   dump(depth, y1, x1, y2, x2);
   ++depth;

   int ym = (y2+y1+1)/2;
   int xm = (x2+x1+1)/2;
   if (y1!=y2 && x1!=x2) {
      if (y1==y2) {
         subdivide(depth, y1, x1, y1, xm-1);
         subdivide(depth, y1, xm, y1, x2);
      }
      else if (x1==x2) {
         subdivide(depth, y1, x1, ym-1, x1);
         subdivide(depth, ym, x1, y2,   x1);
      }
      else {
         subdivide(depth, y1, x1, ym-1, xm-1);
         subdivide(depth, y1, xm, ym-1, x2);
         subdivide(depth, ym, x1, y2,   xm-1);
         subdivide(depth, ym, xm, y2,   x2);
      }
   }
}

int main(void) {
   subdivide(0, 1,1, 8,8);
   printf("\n");
   subdivide(0, 1,1, 7,7);
   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic --std=c99 -o a a.c && a
(0,0)(7,7)
 (0,0)(3,3)
  (0,0)(1,1)
   (0,0)(0,0)
   (0,1)(0,1)
   (1,0)(1,0)
   (1,1)(1,1)
  (0,2)(1,3)
   (0,2)(0,2)
   (0,3)(0,3)
   (1,2)(1,2)
   (1,3)(1,3)
  (2,0)(3,1)
   (2,0)(2,0)
   (2,1)(2,1)
   (3,0)(3,0)
   (3,1)(3,1)
  (2,2)(3,3)
   (2,2)(2,2)
   (2,3)(2,3)
   (3,2)(3,2)
   (3,3)(3,3)
 (0,4)(3,7)
  (0,4)(1,5)
   (0,4)(0,4)
   (0,5)(0,5)
   (1,4)(1,4)
   (1,5)(1,5)
  (0,6)(1,7)
   (0,6)(0,6)
   (0,7)(0,7)
   (1,6)(1,6)
   (1,7)(1,7)
  (2,4)(3,5)
   (2,4)(2,4)
   (2,5)(2,5)
   (3,4)(3,4)
   (3,5)(3,5)
  (2,6)(3,7)
   (2,6)(2,6)
   (2,7)(2,7)
   (3,6)(3,6)
   (3,7)(3,7)
 (4,0)(7,3)
  (4,0)(5,1)
   (4,0)(4,0)
   (4,1)(4,1)
   (5,0)(5,0)
   (5,1)(5,1)
  (4,2)(5,3)
   (4,2)(4,2)
   (4,3)(4,3)
   (5,2)(5,2)
   (5,3)(5,3)
  (6,0)(7,1)
   (6,0)(6,0)
   (6,1)(6,1)
   (7,0)(7,0)
   (7,1)(7,1)
  (6,2)(7,3)
   (6,2)(6,2)
   (6,3)(6,3)
   (7,2)(7,2)
   (7,3)(7,3)
 (4,4)(7,7)
  (4,4)(5,5)
   (4,4)(4,4)
   (4,5)(4,5)
   (5,4)(5,4)
   (5,5)(5,5)
  (4,6)(5,7)
   (4,6)(4,6)
   (4,7)(4,7)
   (5,6)(5,6)
   (5,7)(5,7)
  (6,4)(7,5)
   (6,4)(6,4)
   (6,5)(6,5)
   (7,4)(7,4)
   (7,5)(7,5)
  (6,6)(7,7)
   (6,6)(6,6)
   (6,7)(6,7)
   (7,6)(7,6)
   (7,7)(7,7)

(0,0)(6,6)
 (0,0)(2,2)
  (0,0)(0,0)
  (0,1)(0,2)
   (0,1)(0,1)
   (0,2)(0,2)
  (1,0)(2,0)
   (1,0)(1,0)
   (2,0)(2,0)
  (1,1)(2,2)
   (1,1)(1,1)
   (1,2)(1,2)
   (2,1)(2,1)
   (2,2)(2,2)
 (0,3)(2,6)
  (0,3)(0,4)
   (0,3)(0,3)
   (0,4)(0,4)
  (0,5)(0,6)
   (0,5)(0,5)
   (0,6)(0,6)
  (1,3)(2,4)
   (1,3)(1,3)
   (1,4)(1,4)
   (2,3)(2,3)
   (2,4)(2,4)
  (1,5)(2,6)
   (1,5)(1,5)
   (1,6)(1,6)
   (2,5)(2,5)
   (2,6)(2,6)
 (3,0)(6,2)
  (3,0)(4,0)
   (3,0)(3,0)
   (4,0)(4,0)
  (3,1)(4,2)
   (3,1)(3,1)
   (3,2)(3,2)
   (4,1)(4,1)
   (4,2)(4,2)
  (5,0)(6,0)
   (5,0)(5,0)
   (6,0)(6,0)
  (5,1)(6,2)
   (5,1)(5,1)
   (5,2)(5,2)
   (6,1)(6,1)
   (6,2)(6,2)
 (3,3)(6,6)
  (3,3)(4,4)
   (3,3)(3,3)
   (3,4)(3,4)
   (4,3)(4,3)
   (4,4)(4,4)
  (3,5)(4,6)
   (3,5)(3,5)
   (3,6)(3,6)
   (4,5)(4,5)
   (4,6)(4,6)
  (5,3)(6,4)
   (5,3)(5,3)
   (5,4)(5,4)
   (6,3)(6,3)
   (6,4)(6,4)
  (5,5)(6,6)
   (5,5)(5,5)
   (5,6)(5,6)
   (6,5)(6,5)
   (6,6)(6,6)
```